# Как работает return в рекурсии?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

У меня есть рекурсивная функция, задача которой найти поле

```
findSelectTag(el){
        if(el.children.length > 0 && el.children != undefined){
            
            for(let child of el.children){
                if(child.tagName == "SELECT"){
                    console.log(child)
                    return child;
                }else{
                    this.findSelectTag(child);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

console.log(child) выдает правильный елемент, но return не возврощает ничего(

Comment: В рекурсии должно быть два return (как минимум).

Comment: А куда впихнуть второй ретурн?

Comment: @АндрійПоліщук, хотя бы `return this.findSelectTag(child);`

Comment: @gil9red Я пробовал, не помогло(

Comment: Не правда хоть 100 return.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов да, где написано, что именно два? Я такого не утверждал.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов "как минимум" писал. "Именно" не писал. Для вас это одно и то же?

Comment: Интересно return a>0? F(a-1): a; сколько тут return?

Comment: Можно совсем без `return` ---- `const find = el => (el.children && el.children.length) && [...el.children].reduce((acc, child) => child.tagName == "SELECT" ? acc.concat(child) : acc.concat(find(child) || []), []);`

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть 3 return

Первый if без return на else и второй if else тоже

```
findSelectTag(el){
    if(el.children.length > 0 && el.children != undefined){
        
        for(let child of el.children){
            if(child.tagName == "SELECT"){
                console.log(child);
                return child;
            }else{
                return this.findSelectTag(child);
            }
        }

    } 
   return null;

}
```

Исправлено, не хватало продолжения цикла по элементам

```
findSelectTag(el){
    if(el.children.length > 0 && el.children != undefined){
        
        for(let child of el.children){
            if(child.tagName == "SELECT"){
                console.log(child);
                return child;
            }else{
                if (this.findSelectTag(child)) {
                      return this.findSelectTag(child);
               } else { 
                    continue; // смысла нет но наглядно
               }
            }
        }

    } 
   return null;

}
```

Comment: Больше, больше `return`-ов.

Comment: Не помогло, всё так же

Comment: `return this.findSelectTag(child);` - только если `this.findSelectTag(child)` вернет не `null`.

Comment: A tak посиотрите

Comment: Нет, не угадалось. В конце - `return null;`

Comment: `let c = this.findSelectTag(child); if (c) return c;`

Comment: Уберите последнее `else`.

Comment: А смысл, что то я не вижу

Comment: Хоть смысла нет, но запахало!

Comment: Вcе еще неправильно.

Comment: Это бред щя исправлю

Answer (score 0):

```
findSelectTag(el) {
  for(let i = 0; el.children && i < el.children.length; i++) {
    let child = el.children[i];
    if (child.tagName == "SELECT") {
      return child;
    } else {
      let s = this.findSelectTag(child);
      if (s) return s;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```